# Dumping hardware state of an Intel HD Audio hardware

Tags: linux, audio, kernel

Is there a way to fully dump the configuration of an Intel HDA-based audio codec, including current hardware state?

- The interface at `/proc/asound/card0/codec#0` only reflects what's known to the kernel, not the real hardware state.
- The PCI configuration space (read with `lspci -x`) doesn't show much (it doesn't even show volume/amplifier gain values).

*For context : I'm trying to debug an audio issue with my laptop, where headphones output white noise when resuming from standby. The white noise doesn't change when increasing volume, but disappears only when powering down the codec.*

*This leads me to believe that the issue is likely caused by either a buggy ACPI or a change in the codec's configuration, or even both. My goal is to get as much data as I can on before/after states and compare them, but both methods described above failed for me.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that `hdajackretask` as part of the alsa-tools-gui package on my Debian Stretch GNU/Linux Os looks very interesting in getting the internal parts of the sound-card in the right configuration for what I wanted.

I'm just looking to see whether it is portable to my other OS as I have only seem to have stereo audio on FreeBSD and I think this would help.  In your case it might help your to decode how things are configured and to spot any changes. The normal screen is at least helpful in determining which connection is which:

[image: normal output for Jack retasking on my Realtek ALC1200 soundcard]

What looks more interesting is the "Advanced override":

[image: normal output for Jack retasking on my Realtek ALC1200 soundcard]

I am about to reboot and see whether I have managed to turn the grey connector be the "side"-channel outputs....